# Find the number of permutations of integers from $1$ to $10$ inclusive that do not start with $1$ and do not end with $10$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Find the number of permutations of integers from $1$ to $10$ inclusive that

$a)$ do not start with $1$ and do not end with $10$.

$b)$ no odd integer will be in its right place.

$c)$ numbers $1$, $4$ and $7$ are not in their right places.

For the question $a)$, I tried something like this:

Since the first place cannot be a $1$, there are $9$ ways to fill it. Similarly, the last position can't be a $10$, so there are only $8$ ways to fill it. The remaining digits can be filled in $8!$ ways.

So by rule of product, the answer would be $9 \cdot 8 \cdot 8!$.

But the answer given in the key seems different. I'm not sure if I have gone wrong somewhere in my approach.

Comment: In part a, for the first place, 
you are assuming that regardless of which of the 9 allowable
replacements for "$1$" is used, there will then be only 8 ways of 
filling the last place.  This is true if $2$ through $9$ inclusive
is used in the first place, but not true if $10$ is used in
the first place.  In that situation, there will then be
$9$ rather than only $8$ available choices for the
last place.

Comment: Basically, in part a, you have two choices: [1] The direct approach, which is what you have attempted.  It is certainly do-able, but somewhat complicated. [2] The indirect approach, as *generically* detailed by [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Answer (score 1):

All three parts of this problem can be solved by using the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

> Find the number of permutations of integers from $1$ to $10$ inclusive that do not start with $1$ and do not end with $10$.

We will subtract the number of permutations which start with $1$ or end with $10$ from the total number of permutations.

There are $10!$ permutations of the ten distinct integers $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10$.

If we place a $1$ in the first position, there are $9!$ ways to permute the remaining nine distinct integers in the remaining nine positions.

If we place a $10$ in the last position, there are $9!$ ways to permute the remaining nine distinct integers in the remaining nine positions.

Subtracting those permutations with a $1$ in the first position or a $10$ in the last position from the total number of permutations gives us a preliminary count of
$$10! - 9! - 9!$$
but we have subtracted too much.  We have counted those permutations which have both a $1$ in the first position and a $10$ in the last position twice, once when we subtracted those permutations which have a $1$ in the first position and once when we subtracted those permutations which have a $10$ in the last position.  We only want to subtract such cases once, so we must add them to the total.

If we place a $1$ in the first position and a $10$ in the last position, the remaining eight distinct integers can be permuted in the remaining eight positions in $8!$ ways.

Hence, the number of permutations of the integers $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10$ which do not start with $1$ and do not end with $10$ is
$$10! - 2 \cdot 9! + 8!$$

I suggest that you try part (c) next.  Subtract the number of permutations which have a $1$ in the first position or a $4$ in the fourth position or a $7$ in the seventh position from the total number of permutations by using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.  Doing so is easier than doing part (b) since you have three excluded conditions rather than five.